# How to find descriptors for manualy defined landmarks with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, sift

I am trying to generate "SIFT" descriptor (SIFT is only an example) for some manualy defined landmarks.
When I try to do:

`siftDetector(grayImage, Mat(), manualLandmarks, descriptors, true);`

the result is always 0 (zero) for the descriptors. I have described `manualLandmarks` as `std::vector<cv::KeyPoint>`, and I have changed the x and y coordinates for each item in the vector (the size, octave and angle values are not changed).

Is there a way to define manualy the image coordinates and compute the descriptors for that location?

Thanks.

Comment: it is possible(x,y,octave are the minimal items to fill) but probably a bad idea. most keypoint detectors are complex things, that involve a whole neighbourhood of pixels. maybe it would need a different feature extractor, too (one that is less specialized on sift keypoints)

Comment: That could be a good idea. Could be HoG a good alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cv::Mat I = imread("image.jpg"); // load the image


std::vector<cv::Point2f> inputs;

inputs.push_back(cv::Point(74,114)); // manually defined landmark
inputs.push_back(cv::Point(130,114)); // manually defined landmark 

std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> kp;
for( size_t i = 0; i < inputs.size(); i++ ) {
kp.push_back(cv::KeyPoint(inputs[i], 1.f));
}

cv::Mat descriptors;
cv::SiftFeatureDetector detector;
detector.compute(I, kp, descriptors); // descriptors are the sift descriptors on manually defined landmarks
```